# Cannot access (list) existing directory in git-bash.exe?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, directory, msys

I was working with unpacking Java files in `git-bash.exe` under Windows 2008, and I came to the following state:

```
myUSER@myPC MINGW32 /z/myUSER/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_45_x64
$ ls -la
total 78848
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 12:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:23 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 12:11 jdk1.6.0_45-x64/
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:59 cab_unpack/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249   526848 Nov  6 11:09 jdk1.6.0_45.msi
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 12:16 jre6-x64/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249       36 Nov  6 11:10 sb160450.cab
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:30 sj160450/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249 14582180 Nov  6 11:10 sj160450.cab
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:30 sp160450/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249    36465 Nov  6 11:10 sp160450.cab
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:30 sr160450/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249   130177 Nov  6 11:10 sr160450.cab
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:31 ss160450/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249 17633708 Nov  6 11:09 ss160450.cab
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:31 st160450/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249 29826950 Nov  6 11:10 st160450.cab
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:31 sz160450/
-rw-r--r-- 1 myUSER 1610613249     1638 Nov  6 11:10 sz160450.cab
drwxr-xr-x 1 myUSER 1610613249        0 Nov  6 11:50 uni-jdk1.6.0_45/
```

Notice how there is a directory there `jdk1.6.0_45-x64` which is listed first? I created that one manually... However, now when I try to access it (`cd` to it, or list it):

```
myUSER@myPC MINGW32 /z/myUSER/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_45_x64
$ cd jdk1.6.0_45-x64
bash: cd: jdk1.6.0_45-x64: No such file or directory

myUSER@myPC MINGW32 /z/myUSER/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_45_x64
$ ls jdk1.6.0_45-x64
ls: cannot access jdk1.6.0_45-x64: No such file or directory
```

... it's as if it is not there ??!! I have no problem with the other subdirectories in this directory, either ??!! Interestingly, this directory is shown both in Windows Explorer - and under globbing:

```
myUSER@myPC MINGW32 /z/myUSER/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_45_x64
$ for ix in *; do echo $ix; done
jdk1.6.0_45-x64
cab_unpack
jdk1.6.0_45.msi
jre6-x64
sb160450.cab
sj160450
sj160450.cab
sp160450
sp160450.cab
sr160450
sr160450.cab
ss160450
ss160450.cab
st160450
st160450.cab
sz160450
sz160450.cab
uni-jdk1.6.0_45
```

... but not when I do <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion:

```
$ ls jTAB
jdk1.6.0_45.msi  jre6-x64/
```

How is this possible - that `ls -la .` can list this directory - but `ls`, with the directory name as the argument, is inaccessible ?! What can I do to access this directory from the `git-bash.exe` terminal?

If it is relevant, the version is:

```
myUSER@myPC MINGW32 /z/myUSER/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_45_x64
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(2)-release (i686-pc-msys) ...
```

... installed via `PortableGit-2.5.3-32-bit.7z.exe` - and I think this `git-bash.exe` provides a `msys2` environment...

Comment: What if you use quotes? `cd "jdk1.6.0_45-x64"`

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui - tried quotes, still the same: `ls: cannot access jdk1.6.0_45-x64: No such file or directory`

Comment: What if you try to create a dummy dir and access it? `mkdir mytest; cd mytest`. Just to discard some problems in the dir itself.

Comment: @fedorqui - `mkdir mytest; cd mytest` creates directory fine, and changes into it fine...

Comment: Mmmm weird. I would output the result of `ls` to a file and check if something is weird in the dir name. `ls > tmpfile`, remove all lines but this one, `file=$(cat tmpfile)` and then `ls "$file"`.

Comment: Absolutely right, @fedorqui - if I do that, and just do `cat tmpfile`, I still get "just" `jdk1.6.0_45-x64/`; however, if I do `less tmpfile`, I get `<U+0096>jdk1.6.0_45-x64/`, and with `nano tmpfile`, I get  `┬^Íjdk1.6.0_45-x64/`, so there are some invisible bytes that somehow ended up in the filename... So I just renamed from Windows Explorer - and all seems to work fine now! Thanks!

Comment: Nice! So that was it : ) I don't know if we should close the question as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".